# Linq conditional query in C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following two database tables. A group contains multiple members.

Groups: Id (int) | Name (int)

Members: Id (int) | GroupId (int) | IsExpert (bit)

I need to write a linq to sql query that returns the Groups that has no experts. Need some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer should be those groups where the groups' collection of members doesn't contain any experts (ie `!Any`)

```
context.Groups.Where(group -> !group.Members.Any(member => member.IsExpert));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var GroupsWithNoExperts =
DBDataContext.Groups.Where(
    g=>!DBDataContext.Members.Any(m=>m.GroupID==g.Id && m.IsExpert
));
```